# How can open link from other Apps in my App in Android

Tags: android

I want to open an external link in my app.

For example when the user clicks on `www.example.com/batmanpage` from instagram I want to open this page (Batman page) in my application, as a deep link.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just google "Android deep link". You will get for example:

[this link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

Be careful about the details or your deep link won't work.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        **<!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->**
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In the activity you need to read the values from the intent:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
}
```

If your Activity is not "standard" and if an instance has already been created you will receive the intent in the `onNewIntent` method.

Comment: yes you do. Just follow the link. I'll add something in the answer